# Keep screen alive by using camera

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 3.0-honeycomb, screen-timeout, front-camera

The new Samsung Galaxy S III has an interesting feature which keeps the screen alive (on) if the camera decides the user is reading something by detecting if the user is moving his/her eyes. Does anybody know any application like that in the Android Market which I could install on my Motorola Xoom 2 (Honeycomb) or on my Galaxy S II (ICS) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a BETA version floating around XDA. YMMV. This is being developed particularly for the S2, although it *might* work with other devices having FFCs (Front Facing Cameras) as well.

See [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1708012) for more details.